# Can I dynamically add text next to the mouse cursor via javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Right now I changed the cursor image if any ajax is in a process using this javascript code

```
$(function(){  
  $("html").bind("ajaxStart", function(){  
     $(this).addClass('busy');  
   }).bind("ajaxStop", function(){  
     $(this).removeClass('busy');  
   });  
});
```

and below css

```
    html.busy, html.busy * {  
        cursor: wait !important;  
    }
```

Now I want to add some text next to the cursor too. And remove it when the ajax finishes. How is that possible without using any jQuery plugin?

Comment: *"Is that possible?"* - yes, because a piece of JS code to do that does not have to be a jQuery plugin.

Comment: ok ok :-) , 'how' can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

Demo with start / stop functions and changing text

http://jsfiddle.net/SY4mv/18/

Comment: How can I stop/remove the text? Clicking "stop" doesn't work for me. Why do you use settimeout?

Comment: It's for the 'moving' dots ... Still cannot stop it.

Comment: You missed `$("#besideMouse").html("")` in your stopLoadingBM() function.

Answer (score 3):

See http://jsfiddle.net/PbAjt/show/:

CSS:

```
#cursorText{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid blue; /* You can remove it*/
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.body.onmousemove=moveCursor;
var curTxt=document.createElement('div');
curTxt.id="cursorText";
curTxt.innerHTML="Hello!"; /* Or whatever you want */
document.body.appendChild(curTxt);
var curTxtLen=[curTxt.offsetWidth,curTxt.offsetHeight];
function moveCursor(e){
    if(!e){e=window.event;}
    curTxt.style.left=e.clientX-curTxtLen[0]+'px';
    curTxt.style.top=e.clientY-curTxtLen[1]+'px';
}
```

Depending on what you want you can change

```
curTxt.style.left=e.clientX-curTxtLen[0]+'px';
```

into

```
curTxt.style.left=e.clientX+'px';
```

and

```
curTxt.style.top=e.clientY-curTxtLen[1]+'px';
```

to

```
curTxt.style.top=e.clientY+'px';
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
#tooltip {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;    
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

html.busy #tooltip { opacity: 1 }

html.busy, html.busy * {  
        cursor: wait !important;  
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tooltip">Message</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("html").bind("ajaxStart", function() {
        $(this).addClass('busy');
        $(this).bind('mousemove', function(event) {
            $('#tooltip').css({
                top: event.pageY - $('#tooltip').height() - 5,
                left: event.pageX
            });
        });
    }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
        $(this).removeClass('busy');
        $(this).unbind('mousemove');
    });
});
```

Event DOC: http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/
 ​

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/RGNCq/1/